# iOS Firebase - Facebook authWithOAuthProvider returns incorrect uid

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login, facebook-authentication

I am using Facebook login with firebase in my ios app, but I can't save the user's data to the database because authWithOAuthProvider seems to be returning a differend uid string from the one I can see in the dashboard. Is this a known issue? Here is my code:

```
@IBAction func tappedFacebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {
    User.sharedModel.facebookUser = true
    let loginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email"]
    loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(permissions, fromViewController: self, handler: { fbResult, fbError in
        if fbError != nil {
            // error in login
            print("fbError: \(fbError.code)")
        }
        else if fbResult.isCancelled {
            // cancelled login
            print("cancelled facebook login")
        }
        else {
            // fb logged in
            self.startProgressHud()
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
            FirebaseManager.sharedRootRef.authWithOAuthProvider("facebook", token: accessToken, withCompletionBlock: { error, authData in
                if error != nil {
                    self.handleFirebaseError(error)
                }
                else {
                    // firebase logged in
                    print(authData.uid)
                    self.getUserDataAndLogin(authData.uid)
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: please update with some relevant screenshot to show the exact case.

Answer (score 0):

Found that though the uid printed by `authWithOAuthProvider` is different from the one in the auth dashboard, `authWithOAuthProvider` prints the same one every time so saving and retrieving user data actually works, it's just a different uid that appears in the auth dashboard for that user for some odd reason.